# Why should spring security intercept urls order matter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

SO I have sample Spring security setup as follows -

```
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/search"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_VIEWER')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/*"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

As per above is user has role `ROLE_VIEWER` he should be able to access `/accounts/search` where as user with role `ROLE_ADMIN` has access too all workflows starting with `/accounts`. Here user with `ROLE_ADMIN` is not able to access search.

So I am wondering what could be the usecase for such a design where order matters?

If case of controllers

```
@RequestMapping("/simple/*")
public @ResponseBody String simple1() {
    return "Hello world1!";
}

@RequestMapping("/simple/test")
public @ResponseBody String simple2() {
    return "Hello world2!";
}
```

`/simple/test` would match handler method corresponding to `simple2` rather than `simple1` irrespective of the order.

Answer (score 0):

In general: as soon as you use wildcards in your url-pattern, and urls start to match to differen url-patterns, then the order is important.

A typical usecase is a whitelist for allowed urls: everything is denied (or only for admins) except some explicit defined urls. With spring security you typical configure a white-list this way:

```
<!-- explicit allowed urls -->
<security:intercept-url pattern="/somethingAllowd" access="permitAll" />
... 

<!-- "catch all" that deny all not explicit allowed urls except for admns -->
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

now order matters!